# Search Pandas dataframe column for exact string including punctuation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find email addresses that contain the letters `.ac.` inside them. I have a column in my Pandas dataframe that lists email addresses.

What I am currently doing is:

```
group = mydf['email'].str.contains('.ac.', na = False)
```

However, this returns all email addresses that contain `ac` rather than `.ac.` (missing the full stops). This means that `group` includes any email addresses that have ac in them e.g. `aclaim@gmail.com` which is incorrect. I want to only return emails like `john@cambridge.ac.uk`

Is it possible for me to search for exactly `.ac.`?

Comment: I did not check if it works, but perhaps `\.ac\.` would do it?

Comment: Oh amazing, that worked! Feel free to leave as an answer if you want to be accepted. Can I ask why this works?

Comment: @TomMac Using the pattern `\.` within a regular expression matches a literal `.` since, by default, the dot `.` is a metacharacter in regex that matches any character except a newline.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I didn't realise str.contains was using regex by default. Thanks ombk.

Comment: @TomMac just wrote that as an answer, didnt notice ur comment but at least u got it right ^_^

Comment: Did not know the exact reason, had a feeling it would help :). Thanks for the explanation @ombk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will develop @itaishz answer.

`pd.Series.str.contains(...)` has a parameter called `regex` that is set by default as `True`. Meaning that your pattern will be match as a `regex` and not `literally`.

Therefore, you had to use the trick of `\.ac\.` for it to work.

However, by setting the parameter to `False` , you could achieve your result directly.

```
lis1 = ["abuali.ac.laska" ,"nono",",ac", "lol.ac.lol"]
ser = pd.Series(lis1)
ser[ser.str.contains(".ac.",regex=False)]

#output
0    abuali.ac.laska
3         lol.ac.lol
dtype: object
```

And please dont mind the stupid example (lol).